# How to generate random div id inside Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to render 2 charts using a **directive**. The chart requires a unique target div to render; however, it appears my directive is generating a single instance of the control and not a second.  Do I need to pass an id through parent scope instead? I have tried an implementation of id="graph_{{$id}}", but that doesn't work.

**Directive Snippet:** Generate random number and assign to target div tag

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999) + 1);

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',  // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
        replace: true,
        scope: { //binds scope
            val: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="graph_' + num + '"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 

        var dcPie = dc.pieChart("#graph_" + num);
```

**HTML:** Add two instances of the directive

```
<my-dc-graph val="graphPie"></my-dc-graph><br>
<my-dc-graph val="graphPie2"></my-dc-graph>
```

**Resulting HTML:** Only one control renders, the second remains empty with the same unique id

```
<div id="graph_432240223" val="graphPie" class="ng-isolate-scope dc-chart">... Chart SVG renders just fine here ...</div>
<div id="graph_432240223" val="graphPie2" class="ng-isolate-scope dc-chart">... Nothing ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.Random is not truely random if you call it like that, because it is based on your timestamp. Try and force some extra miliseconds of time between the Math.Random() to ensure they are seeded with different values, or just make sure you determine the random number externally.

Comment: That is an interesting observation, so I implemented it by converting the random variable to use d.getMilliseconds(), unfortunately this did not work as both div tags rendered with the same id="dc-pie245".